# Wait for any background progress going on in eclipse while testing using SWT Bot

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swtbot

I wanted to wait for any operation that are happening in eclipse and then proceed with the test-case, so I need to see if any operation are happening in the background, this is shown in Progress view, but I am unable to get any information using swtbot. **How to wait for any background progress going on in eclipse while testing using SWT-Bot?**
The Progres view prints **No operations to display at this time.** when all operation are over, but I dont know how to read for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, this is how i did it:

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().run(new IWorkspaceRunnable() {
            @Override
            public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {
                //Do nothing
            }
        }, new NullProgressMonitor());
    }
```

This submits job to ResourcePlugin and hence it waits till all resource change related process complete.
To handle the launch/debug process, I get all the launches active and if current project launch is active, I wait for its termination (This has a problem in linux, the isTerminated() function for a launch always return true, even after it is terminated, so I added a timeout while waiting).
To get all launches:

```
org.eclipse.debug.core.ILaunch launch = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager().getLaunches();
```

To check if it terminated:

```
launch.isTerminated();
```

Source: [Eclipse GUI testing is viable](http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/eclipse-gui-testing-is-viable-)